# How to adjust top always "dropdown-menu Bootstrap 3"

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm looking for a way to getting a dropdown-menu> li is open always appear in the same location top.

**When we launched the first dropdown-menu**

[image]

when we launched other dropdown-menu > li > a

[image]

I'm using bootstrap 3, do not worry about the responsive I've completely removed, I need all the dropdown-menu start at the same top of the first dropdown-menu> li> a

```
.dropdown-menu {
  background-clip: padding-box;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  // border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.176);
  display: none;
  float: left;
  font-size: 14px;
  // left: 0;
  left: 100%;
  list-style: none outside none;
  // margin: 2px 0 0;
  min-width: 160px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  // top:100%; i'm tried set 0 but not work..
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can give you code if u mention your code or jsfiddle.

Use Position:absolute (!impotant if required) on the right-dropdown(contains action, another action etc.) give top:0 and left = width of the first-menu(which contains Ropas, Telephonos etc)
that makes the right-dropdown stay always on top

Comment: i'm use the same "Drop Down Menu" Bootstrap 3, but need when click in "Ropa or Telephonos" dropdown-menu need align in the same open "Jojería Relojes."

Comment: @user3258963 i perfetly understand your problem. I will edit my answer and explain it in a detailed way.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this..

```
.dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
}
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/126758